# Enabling disabled Asus NumberPad

Tags: windows-11, asus-laptop, device-manager, input-device

I have found [these instructions](https://www.coolblue.be/en/advice/how-do-you-turn-off-the-numeric-keypad-in-the-touchpad-of-your-asus-laptop.html) for disabling the Asus NumberPad via Windows Device Manager.

However, before I disable it, I need to know how to enable it back again in case I need it.

**Additional information**

1. Manufacturer: Asus
2. Model: Zenbook UM3402YA_UM3402YA

Comment: Hello, what exactly is your goal? Looks like XY problem. And those instructions don't seem too proper.

Comment: @Destroy666 When I work on my Asus Zenbook, if I accidentally touch the upper right corner of the touch pad, the Number Pad activates. Now, I have successfully disabled the Number Pad via Device Manager, yet I cannot find a way to enable the Number Pad back again.

Comment: So you should have looked into disabling the button itself, perhaps. Maybe you could have remapped it with AHK or anything. To reenable the feature, you'll need to ofc reinstall the driver. Can't say which one without knowing the model.

Comment: Dxdiag reports: `Zenbook UM3402YA_UM3402YA`

Comment: @Destroy666 Done. If I am missing some info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reenable NumberPad on Asus Zenbook UM3402YA after you uninstalled the driver, you can:

1. Go to [this page](https://www.asus.com/us/laptops/for-home/zenbook/zenbook-14-oled-um3402/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=UM3402YA) with drivers for the model.
2. Scroll to `Pointing Device` and click `See All Downloads`.
3. Download the latest version of `ASUS NumberPad Driver` listed there and install it.

You might alternatively be able to reinstall it through MyASUS software, but not sure if it'd be listed there after uninstall.

I wouldn't recommend (re)installing it back and forth. Instead I would check if clicking on the button to enable NumberPad sends a key code readable and remappable by applications like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).